# Is there a timer indicator?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, indicator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A simple timer app, similar to timer-applet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14257/a-simple-timer-app-similar-to-timer-applet)

On 10.10 I've used timer-applet and was pretty happy with it. After upgrading to 11.04 I can't find any way of using this timer.

What countdown timer program do you recommend to use with ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: This question looks like a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/14257/8116 -- a few answers have been provided there

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but you should be able to install Docky and then the timer-applet on it.
Check [Install Docky Stacks From An Ubuntu PPA](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/install-docky-stacks-from-ubuntu-ppa.html)
and, [Enhance your productivity with Docky’s timer applet](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/enhance-your-productivity-with-dockys-timer-applet-the-pomodoro-technique/).

Comment: If I understand it correctly the docky is nearly the same thing as the launcher and I don't think it is a good idea to have to things doing the same work.